# Need to loop through rows and add new record or ignore if exists, replacing string value in main table with identity from lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have a raw data table in SQL Server. I will be creating normalized table where some of the columns with string values will be replaced with identities taken from look up tables.

For example, employer name column in raw table has string data type. I need to replace it with identity value (integer) from the Employer look up table but I need to add possible new employer names to look up table first from raw data table.

Comment: I think you forgot to add sample data and ask a question

Comment: What have you already tried? Please post any queries you came up with.

Comment: I was thinking about creating temp table with EmployerName field and going against existing Employer Lookup table which has two fields: [EmployerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Employer Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL                             but I am new to sql and my raw table field (Employer name) is just string value and it has about 100,000 records. I am stack.

Answer (score 0):

So if you already have a temp table with a string column then you'll need to normalize things. First add a FK (foreign key) column, populate it, then remove the old string column.  Something like this:

```
--Your starting point
CREATE TABLE tmp(EmployerName varchar(100))
CREATE TABLE Employee([EmployerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [Employer Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL)

--Add a foreign key field to your tmp table
ALTER TABLE tmp add EmployerID int

--Update your new foreign key
UPDATE tmp set EmployerID=e.EmployerID
FROM
    tmp
    inner join Employee e on e.[Employer Name] = tmp.EmployerName

--Finally, remove your old denormalized string column 
--and just use the EmployeeID field going forward.
ALTER TABLE tmp drop column EmployerName
```

Comment: Just tried it, worked like a charm. Thanks again. You are Awesome!